# Ideal polynomial equations in Macaulay2

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, computer-algebra-systems, macaulay2

Given a known ring $R$ and an ideal $I\subseteq R$, I would like to be able to solve an "ideal polynomial equation" of the form $$\sum_i I_i^{\alpha_i}=I,$$ i.e to find ideals $I_i$ so that the above equation holds. I would want to have a list of all possible solutions.

An example of something I would want to solve is  the ideal equation $$(IJ)^5+I^3J^2+I^2J^3+I=R$$ where $R$ is a ring of the form $R=k[x_1, \cdots, x_m]/K$ where $K$ is some known finitely general ideal of $R$.

Could this be coded in Macaulay2?

Comment: Is this sufficiently well defined? Certainaly such $I$ and $J$ are not unique, do you want to find all such ideals? If you only want a solution the $I = R$ or $J = R$ will always work.

Comment: @Mummytheturkey Indeed I want all solutions.

Comment: @Mummytheturkey Or at the very least a few non-trivial ones.